# monitoring local admin remote login

Tags: authentication, networking, windows

Using SIEM system, how can I monitor the event of someone remote login into a computer using a local adminstrator account ?

By using RDP you can remote login using local adminstrator account into a computer without even being in the domain. In the case where the password of the local adminstrator is the same in the whole network and the hash stored in the SAM (file) of one of the computers is compromised,  one can access any workstation he wants without being in the domain or being spotted.

How can I detect remote login of local adminstrator ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product support, and you'll need to direct it to the specific provider (or users) of the SIEM platform that  you're using.

Comment: not siem in specific ... any system in that matter.
i want to know the way ... like which authentication pkg or event id things that r specific to rdp using local user..

Answer (score 0):

Check Security log in Windows Event Log. All logon events are registered here. Use find (or filter) to search for specified accounts events.

Comment: he has to enable active directory auditing and then for logon search events with id 4624